# No AVD's Available message in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I keep running into an issue where Eclipse returns `No AVD's Available` when trying to run code in the emulator.

Checked for updates, restarted Eclipse, confirmed permissions on the `~/.android` dir, and all other options have been tried.

The only thing I do different, which shouldn't make a difference, I run the Android SDK in Zend Studio, which is Eclipse, and I've never had an issue with this until now.

Anyone got any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was stupid...

The AVD list gets blanked out if a real device is plugged in via USB.

As soon as I unplugged it, all my AVD's displayed right away.

If an AVD is running, and then the device is plugged in, both are available in the Running Device window.